# English, Latin, or Malay pronunciation of betta fish

Tags: pronunciation, latin

The genus name of the aquarium fish *Betta splendens* derives from the Malay word "ikan betah." The common name of the fish is also "betta," which in English we'd pronounce with a soft e. I often hear the pronunciation "bay-tuh," for both common and genus name, and just as often hear fish fanciers loudly object and insist on the soft e. But would it also be correct to use a Latin pronunciation for the genus name, which I think (not sure) would be closer to "bay-tuh"?

Comment: Correct according to who?

Comment: "Correct" according to ichthyologists, animal taxonomists, science editors at NPR and the BBC, aquarists, and you, curiousdanni. The little Latin I know leads me to the "ay" pronunciation, but "Betta" isn't really latinized the way plant binomials are, so I'm asking for input from anybody with any of that expertise.

Comment: This is where dictionaries come in handy. Merriam-Webster says *betta* rhymes with feta. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/betta

Comment: Are we discussing English, Malay or Latin here? It seems to me we should be giving priority in pronunciation to the Malay.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how Anglophones *might* pronounce a foreign word.

Comment: I don't believe the question is off-topic. It arises from controversy among English-speaking fish fanciers. My reason for mentioning other languages relates to its English etymology -- the word "betta" originated from a Malay word, was adopted into the "Latin" scientific classification system, and has also become the common English name of a popular fish. Dictionaries tell us to pronounce "betta" with a soft e, just as it's spelled. But people using the scientific terminology for the genus "Betta" don't seem to agree on a pronunciation. Like many English words, it has a history.

Comment: Funnily enough, the _bay-tuh_ pronunciation seems to be more Greek inspired than Latin. The Latin name, with double _t_ would cause few people to pronounce a long vowel sound for the _e_. But the way you transcribe the Malay name, _betah_, is reminiscent of the second letter of the _Greek_ alphabet, often pronounced as _bey-ta_ or _bay-tu_ (by speakers of English and others. Not by Greeks, who now call it something closer to _vee-ta_.)

Comment: I love this question! The double "t" after the "e" would affect the pronunciation of the "e" by making it soft.  Would the word "bettor" be pronounced "bee-tor"?  Of course not.  A soft "e" turned away wrath.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/87353

Comment: In pet stores, I have heard it pronounced *bayta* because the signs read "beta" and not betta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is [all of the above, any of the above, or none of the above.](http://glassbox-design.com/2009/pronouncing-scientific-names-more-difficult-than-you-think/) There is no single set of rules for the pronunciation of taxa, and no single interpretation of [such rules](http://capewest.ca/pron.html) as some have attempted to compile. As Michael G. Simpson notes under "[Pronunciation of Names](http://books.google.com/books?id=Ia2eIPVksMMC&pg=PA511&lpg=PA511#v=onepage&q&f=false)" in *Plant Systematics* (2006),

> Although scientific names are universal, their pronunciations may vary from region to region, especially between different countries. For example, European pronunciations are often different from those of most American botanists. There are no firm rules as to how scientific names should be pronounced. Very often, pronunciations are influenced by one's native language. One should be flexible and adaptive with regard to pronunciations, as the overriding goal is communications.

Broadly, most English-speaking practitioners of science, medicine, law, architecture, and other disciplines follow [traditional English pronunciation of Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_English_pronunciation_of_Latin) for the Latin and quasi-Latin terms in their fields. There are those who push for what is known as [Reformed Academic Pronunciation](http://archive.spectator.co.uk/article/6th-april-1907/10/the-pronunciation-of-latin), a system devised in the late 19th century which is supposed to be closer to the classical pronunciation, and which is closer to the way the words would be pronounced in most continental European languages. William Stearn favors the latter in his widely cited *Botanical Latin* (1983), but as countless papers, guides, and appendices note:

- Professionals not only use different pronunciations from one place to another, but do not consistently follow the same system themselves.
- People tend to pronounce names based on how they first hear them, as opposed to a particular system of pronunciation
- English speakers don't agree on how to pronounce English; how would they agree on how to pronounce any other language or pseudo-language? (Yes, I am one of those people who is always going on about *bruschetta*— it's Italian, not French or German.)

Zoologists and bacteriologists moved away from requiring a classical basis for names some time ago, and botanists have [moved in the same direction](http://www.washingtonpost.com/pb/lifestyle/style/botanists-agree-to-loosen-latins-grip/2012/01/09/gIQAANVe8P_story.html), so perhaps there will be less debate in the future.

Comment: Thank you, choster. That's an excellent answer. I do remember my esteemed mycology prof pronouncing the i in the genus _Amanita_ as "eye" (contrary to most experts), and his advice to "say it with confidence and you'll be OK."

Comment: @choster If _bruschetta_ irks you, you should here what people around here tend to do to _chorizo_. (Hint: a more accurate spelling for how they pronounce it might be _koritcho_.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Oh heavens, the horror! But, this can only be expected of trying to pronounce things in a language that has nearly zero exact rules on how to pronounce any letter. Many English teachers love to point out that *ghoti* can be pronounced *fish*, after all, by way of logic.

Comment: For the record, the Malay pronunciation of _beta_ would sound quite like English _betta_; Malay /e/ would be  undiphthongized, like English /ɛ/ in _bet_.

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment on Malay pronunciation. (It's unclear to me how much direct influence the Malay pronunciation of *betah* has had on the English pronunciation of *Betta/betta*.)

"Bay-tuh" is not really a more Latin pronunciation of *Betta.* There are various systems for pronouncing Latin, but in nearly all of them the vowel in the first syllable of *Betta* would be a monophthong (a pure vowel sound), and the sound found in English "bay" is usually a diphthong [eɪ].

*Betta* obviously did not exist in the Classical Latin era (the earliest date on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betta) page is 1910). But based on the typical correlations between Latin spelling and pronunciation, a Classical-Latin-style pronunciation of *Betta* would most likely be something like [bɛtta]. This is about the same as the pronunciation in what is called "Ecclesiastical" Latin. The vowel in the first syllable would be similar to the vowel in English words *bet, better.* In theory, the spelling *Betta* is also consistent with a pronunciation with a long vowel in the first syllable (which in reconstructed Classical pronunciation would be something like [beːtta]), but it was somewhat unusual, although not impossible, for a long vowel to occur before a double consonant in Latin.

In traditional English pronunciation, there is no question that the double consonant would regularly call for the use of a "short e" sound /ɛ/ (as in *bet*): we see this pronunciation used in English even in words that are thought to have been pronounced with a long vowel before a double consonant in Classical Latin, such as *stella.*

There are a few Latinate words/terms/names aside from *betta* where you might hear a "long" vowel pronounced before a consonant that is written double, but these pronunciations are all irregular (and for this reason, some people might criticize them as "mispronunciations"). The words I know of that have irregular pronunciations like this are *cam**e**llia, amp**u**llae, b**u**ccal, med**u**lla, cor**o**lla.*

Comment: For languages with both /ɛ/ and /e/, we often distinguish between them in English by using /ɛ/ and /eɪ/. So the monophthong/diphthong question is more or less irrelevant. But it looks like this is irrelevant for Malay.

Answer (score 1):

The famous ichthyologist William T Innes says in the Innes book that the correct pronunciation is Betta - just as it looks and he specifically says it is not Bayta. My father and I bred and raised them when I was a child and all of the fish people in the 1970's pronounced  it correctly. It was not until the 1990's when people stopped reading as much and began to degenerate that I begin to hear it pronounced incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Bèt-táh    it is as simple as *better* but with an 'a' at the end instead of 'er'  at the end.

Comment: We generally expect answers to include an authoritative source.